# XLSXWriter FILTER(): Reference to Other Worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

I have a tab called Sheet1. It filters data from a tab called `Data_Summary`.

If I enter this FILTER() function in cell A2 of Sheet1, and hit return:

```
=FILTER(Data_Summary!A20:B91,Data_Summary!B20:B91="Assigned")
```

...everything works as expected:

[image]

But if I enter this via XLSXWriter:

```
worksheet.write_array_formula("A2:B73", "=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(Data_Summary!A20:B91,Data_Summary!B20:B91=\"Assigned\")")
```

...the filter still works, but in the rows following the rows that were filtered in, I get a lot of rows containing `#N/A`.

[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a lot of N/A values because you are defining a bigger array than the returned results. In the case that you are entering the FILTER() function manually it autocompletes according to how many results it returns. But with xlsxwriter i couldn't find a way to write the formula except for using the write_array_formula method and defining a specific range. This is not convenient because i suppose that most of the times you do not know how many results you will get.

I found a solution by counting how many occurences of the string 'Assigned' you have in your range and then use this number as the ending row for the array of the formula. But this requires you to have imported your dataframe through pandas. As far as i know there is no way to read a cell's value with xlsxwriter and use it later in the formula, maybe John could shed more light upon this.

Here is a working example based on the information that you provided us:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Cretae a test df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Track Number': ['Track #1','Track #2','Track #3','Track #4','Track #5',
                                    'Track #6','Track #7','Track #8','Track #9','Track #10'],
                   'Status': ['Assigned',np.nan,'Assigned',np.nan,np.nan,
                              'Assigned','Assigned',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

# Start the xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# You could count them using excel's native formula but you will not be able to store it
# into a variable as the formulas are calculated when the file opens
#worksheet.write_formula('D1', '=COUNTIF(Data_Summary!B:B,"Assigned")')

# Using pandas is possible though
# Use loc or iloc for specific range, otherwise pass in the whole column df['Status']
count = df.loc[0:10,'Status'].str.count('Assigned').sum()
worksheet.write_array_formula(f'A1:B{count}', '=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(Data_Summary!A1:B11,Data_Summary!B1:B11="Assigned")')

# Pass the main df to a second sheet named Data_Summary
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data_Summary', index=False)

writer.save()
```

***OUTPUT***:

Main df:

[image]

Result:
[image]

If i define a bigger range than the returned results, for example:

```
worksheet.write_array_formula('A1:B8', '=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(Data_Summary!A1:B11,Data_Summary!B1:B11="Assigned")')
```

i get back #N/As:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this info, Dimitris. I guess I'll hide columns A and B and in columns D and E do something like, `=IF(ISNA(A2),"",A2)`

Comment: That's one way to do it indeed! A 3rd way would be to inject a macro, you would just need to open the file and run it.

Comment: *As far as i know there is no way to read a cell's value with xlsxwriter and use it later in the formula, maybe John could shed more light upon this.* That is correct.

Comment: Good answer btw. These formulas that apply to a (somewhat) indeterminate range will be difficult to work with.